# How to avoid using List<List<T>>?

Tags: c#

I have a WCF service that i cannot touch which returns `List<FilesWithSettings>`. 
I need to enter few PC which are grouped together and retrieve `List<FilesWithSettings>` for each one along with `PCIdentifier` which brings me to `Dictionary<PCIdentifier,List<FilesWithSettings>>` or `List<PCIdentifier>` and `List<List<FilesWithSettings>>` which isn't elegant and unreadable.

Can you give me more elegant solution ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess you've got three options:

```
List<List<T>> // Which is pretty nasty
```

or:

```
Dictionary<PCIdentifier, List<T>>
```

Which better enunciates your intent or even:

```
class PCResult
{
    PCIdentifier Identifier { get; set; };
    List<T> Results { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
List<PCResult>
```

Personally I prefer the third, but the second is fine too.

Comment: Seems like what i'm going to do... Thanks.

Comment: @eugeneK since Jackson gave 3 options, it might be useful to later readers to indicate **which** option you are referring to.

Comment: The third one, which is exactly like yours except the fact i can't change anything related to WCF service. Moreover in my question i've said i don't like List<List<T>> and Dictionary<T,List<T>>

Answer (score 5):

I would have something like

```
[DataContract]
public class PCState // need a better name
{
    [DataMember]
    public PCIdentifier Identifier {get;set;}
    [DataMember]
    public List<FilesWithSettings> Files {get;set;}
}
```

and return a `List<PCState>`. This avoids all the issues with complex overly-generic types and nested lists, etc, and is easily consumed.

Comment: PCFileState would be better name... So you advice to set Data Class for that?

Comment: "So you advice to set Data Class for that?" - I don't quite understand the question. If you mean `[DataContract]` etc - you mentioned WCF, and `[DataContract]`/`[DataMember]` is the *usual* way of expressing our serialization intent for WCF. If you are using a different serialization metaphor, then just use whatever applies to that.

Comment: Sorry i can't change WCF serialization.

Comment: @eugeneK I didn't ask you to. Your question, however, starts: "I have a WCF service"; the attributes I added were merely to illustrate what is typically used over a WCF service. If I'm misunderstanding you, fine... if the `PCFileState` (etc) doesn't go over the service at any point, then fine: remove the attributes.

Answer (score 2):

`Dictionary<PCIdentifier,List<FilesWithSettings>>` is actually pretty elegant. You can clearly identify individual PCs and iterate over all PCs, but also get all data you need for each PC.